# Where to find the network topology of Iridium-Next?

Tags: artificial-satellite, communication, communication-satellite, satellite-constellation

This is my first post on Space Exploration. I'll preface this by saying that I just started learning how satellite communications work from a technical perspective. Until a few days ago I had never heard of phased array antennas or a Ka-band and all I'm learning comes from the Internet.

---

I need to find the network topology of Iridium-Next and any constraints on its inter-satellite connections such as maximum number of links per satellite, maximum distance between two satellites in order to establish a link and the average bit rate.
From what I have read, Iridium-Next satellites are arranged in blocks [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iridium_satellite_constellation)] and each satellite is connected to up to 4 neighbors via Ka-band links [[2]](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/i/iridium-next).
Unfortunately, I can't find the information I need: **which satellites are connected to each other?**
I found the [TLE data on celestrak](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/table.php?GROUP=iridium-NEXT&FORMAT=tle) and I could analyse the orbits to identify satellite subgroups, but with this data I could only guess at the connections.
Also, [in this article](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Network-topology-of-the-Iridium-constellation-a-3D-graphics-and-b-2D-graphics_fig4_315065187) the authors talk about exceptions in links, so I really need an official network topology:

> Most satellites maintain four ISLs (two
> intra-plane ISLs and two inter-plane ISLs) with neighboring satellites, except those at high latitudes whose
> inter-plane ISLs are turned off.

Consider for example the following images (from [CelesTrak Orbit Visualization](https://celestrak.org/cesium/orbit-viz.php?tle=/NORAD/elements/gp.php?GROUP=iridium-NEXT&satcat=/pub/satcat.txt&orbits=0&referenceFrame=1)).

1. Satellites Iridium 107, 165, 163, 114 moved southward and I guess they are in the same group, thus they are always connected in adjacent pairs. Rather than having to look at orbits I would prefer a list of these fixed connections.
2. Iridium 149 (on the right) moved northward so it is in a different group and has fixed connections with other satellites. Iridium 114 and Iridium 149 approach each other and then move away: I guess that they establish a temporary link to connect the two groups of satellites to which they belong. What are the distances at which this temporary connection begins and ends ?

### 2022-04-03 21:59:00Z

[image]

### 2022-04-03 22:01:47Z

[image]

Comment: Hi Wippo. I think you may need to clarify. Where you ask " which satellites are connected to each other?": what is it you want there that is not answered by the quote and the Figure 4 diagram in the RG link?  Do you want to know which precise real-world satellite identifiers connect with each other. The latter sounds like an orbit visualisation problem rather than a networks question.

Comment: Hi @Puffin. As I understand it, there are satellites that are always connected to each other via fixed links. Satellites are arranged in groups that move along two opposite directions (question link [1]): satellites on the edge of different groups can establish temporary links. I would like to have 1) for each real satellite X, the set of satellites always connected to X 2) the distances that determine the beginning and end of a temporary link between two satellites that belong to different groups